# Mount socket server as drive/directory

Tags: sockets, filesystems, distributed, mount

I'm experimenting with sockets and distributed file systems... till now I started my socket-server on PC A and sent my files using CURL to the server. The server decides if the file will be stored on the same machine or on another server (let's say PC B). By storing the file sent using CURL on another server, PC A send the file to PC B. That's working actually, but I'm looking for a way to work without CURL or something else... what I want is that I can use my socket-server like a normal file system.
My idea is that I start my server on PC A, this will mount the directory (let's say /mnt/myFiles) and I can use the directory like a normal file system (store, delete or modify my files). By starting the socket server on PC B, this will extend the capacity of my storage on PC A. Assume, I'll save a file on PC A, this will decide if the file will be storage on PC A or B - completely transparent for the user.
Is there any chance to realize something like that? I already searched some threads in many different forums but I found nothing like this...

Comment: So... you want to write a network filesystem? Why don't use you an existing network filesystem like NFS or sshfs?

Comment: I already thought, this will be the first question... I don't want using something like this because I want learn something. I can read tutorials, forums and so on and understand the theory behind this, but my intension is to implement something - theory is good, implementation is better ;). In addition to this, if everyone uses given things, nothing will be changed and we would still use Windows 1.0 or similar ;).

Comment: Well, writing a new kind of network filesystem is obviously quite ambitious! I'd start by looking at the code for [some sample fuse filesystems](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems). fuse is the easiest way to implement a filesystem because you don't have to write kernel code and it is compatible with a few different popular operating systems (but still, not across the board). Start with [hello world](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/helloworld.html) just to see how a fuse filesystem is written and then look at something simple like http://httpfs.sourceforge.net/